# How to change the setting file of KA lite written by Python

Tags: python

```
# This is the default location where the kalite command finds its settings
# You can change the below lines to use different default settings or
# you can run kalite <command> --settings=other_module

from kalite.project.settings.base import *

# from kalite.project.settings.dev import *
# from kalite.project.settings.raspberry_pi import *

# Put your custom settings here
# MY_SETTING = 123
```

How to change the Downloading location by changing the setting file above?

Answer (score 0):

```
CONTENT_ROOT = "<path to desired content folder>" (default=/home/user/.kalite/content)
```

This the path where KA lite will look for videos to play and download.
You can find out more about it [here](http://ka-lite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usermanual/userman_admin.html#configuration-settings) and [here](http://ka-lite.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usermanual/userman_admin.html#downloading-videos-in-bulk).

Comment: I mean to change the downloading location